# Android: Error while passing int from one activity to another

Tags: android

I am reading my DB in `Activity A` - Fetching `String`, `int`, `String`.
I am passing this to `Activity B` and want to display it in 3 Text fields
The `String` values get displayed properly, but the `int` gives me this error

```
01-03 15:39:48.252: E/ERROR(980): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1f4
```

My code

Activity A

```
Intent myintent2 = new Intent(MoneySummaryPage.this,EnterBankDetails.class);
myintent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
myintent2.putExtra("bank", updateBank);
myintent2.putExtra("amount", updateAmt);
myintent2.putExtra("Currency", updateCur);
myintent2.putExtra("constant", "1");
startActivity(myintent2);
```

Activity B

```
    BankName =      (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bankNameLabel);
    BalanceAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.balanceLabel);
    currencySpin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.currencySpinner);

    constantpass = getIntent().getExtras().getString("constant");

    BankName.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("bank"));
    BalanceAmount.setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("amount", 0));
```

The `BalanceAmount` is the `Integer` field and I am getting blank values there.
Also, my third `String` is to be populated in the Spinner? Can someone tell me the code for populating that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
 BalanceAmount.setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("amount", 0)+"");
```

The problem is , when you try to provide a int value to setText(), the system looks for the resource file with that int id. It might not understand the difference between a int value and a int res(R.String.someValue is considered as int in android).

Now with the above piece of code, the int is now converted to String and hence you will not have any problem and of course you are reducing two lines of code to one.

Comment: thanks, this worked. Can you help me with the spinner code? How do i get myintent2.putExtra("Currency", updateCur); into my Spinner ?

Answer (score 2):

The TextView value should be a String, not an int.

this is the the proper way to do this:

`int iAmount = getIntent().getIntExtra("amount", 0);`
`BalanceAmount.setText(String.valueOf(iAmount));`

Answer (score 0):

To update your `Spinner` use the `View.invalidate()` method.

Or the `Adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` Method

Comment: Well if you set up the adapter for the Spinner keep an instance of the adapter. After you added the data to it, call Adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()